# Getting InfoPath Form Library Fields using C# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, csom, xml, console-application

I need to extract InfoPath form fields in C# using Client Side Object Model(CSOM) and convert it into XML file.

The code which I tried to get FormLibrary fields is

```
   // Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
        // server running SharePoint. 
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteURL/");

        // Assume the web has a list named "Announcements". 
        List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyFormLibrary");

        // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
        // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in. 
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
        ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query);

        // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
        {
            // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
            Console.WriteLine( listItem["Title"]);
        }
```

I am getting `Title` field as name of xml file but when I debug it, giving me error in StackTrace as

> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String
>   propName)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.get_Name()

can anyone please help me !!! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code at my end and I found something useful for you.

Please replace your `foreach` loop with this code and try again.

```
 foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
            {
                // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
                Console.WriteLine("Item : {0}, Id : {1}", listItem.FieldValues["Title"], listItem.Id, listItem.FieldValues["YourField"]);

                var fileRef = listItem.FieldValues["FileRef"];
                FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef.ToString());

                using (var memory = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
                    int nread = 0;
                    while ((nread = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
                    }
                    memory.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(memory);
                }
                //Console.WriteLine( listItem["Title"] + listItem.File.Name);
                Console.ReadKey();


            }
```

Now you will be getting XML data. Please find following snap which I got while running my code.

[image]

Let me know you were looking for this only.

Comment: hey @aakash thanks a lot it worked for me perfectly and this is all i want